# How to insert new items with Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an entity class called `Task` which is mapped in hibernate.

I'm able to fetch existing items belonging to this class correctly, so I don't think this is an issue with the mapping of the class.

However, when I try to insert a new item, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:680)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:672)
```

In the following code:

```
Task t = new Task();
t.title = "foo";
t.comment = "bar";
//snip... (every single field of task is given some value, except for id)

session.saveOrUpdate("Task", t); //This is the line on which the exception occurs
```

If I don't do `saveOrUpdate()`, then the new task isn't inserted into the db.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: `session.save(task)` doesn't work either

Comment: @Youngistan I see no insert or update sql, the last query it shows before throwing the exception is: `Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        hibernate_sequence for update`

Comment: Can you try session.save(t);

Comment: @Youngistan Just tried that, it gives the same error

Comment: Can anyone confirm if `public long id = 0;` for id is allowed?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I've changed that to just `public long id`, however it has no effect.

Comment: Can you execute the statement manually to see if works `select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence`

Comment: Task class has many-to-many relation with User table so can you create set of User and then add this to task object and then save it

Comment: Tried this session.getTransaction().commit(); after save();?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I don't have that table in my database. Which table do I need to run it against?

Comment: @Youngistan I'm already doing that when the class is intantiated? `    public Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();`.

Comment: @Gk. Already doing that. My updates in other tables are working.

Comment: You only create Set but size is 0, just create the User object set in the task object and then save it

Comment: @ClickUpvote You can have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` configured to `update` that will create necessary tables. Else you can create them manually.

Comment: @Youngistan I have tried adding some users to the set via `task.users.add( userObject )`, however still getting the same error.

Comment: So i guess you don't paste complete exception stack trace.Can you paste it because we dnt saw why the exception is Caused by: ??

Comment: @Youngistan that's the complete trace, the error is caused on the `session.saveOrUpdate()` line

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I've set that config setting to true, and now I'm getting an additional exception in my stack trace: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myDb.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist`

Comment: @SubirKumarSao according to http://www.coderanch.com/t/487173/ORM/databases/hibernate-sequence-exist its looking for sequence tables to generate the id? I'm using mysql, so I want to use the normal auto_increment of mysql for making the ids.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Already answered you. Create the table or let hibernate create it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Got this to work with the help of this link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/487173/ORM/databases/hibernate-sequence-exist

Apparently hibernate looks for sequence tables for generating the id. Setting the following:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

on the id, causes it to use the underlying db's auto increment and not try to generate the id itself, and now it works.

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally removed hibernate_sequence table in my db.
Change:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

In your application.properties file
so Hibernate could recreate this table by himself

Comment: "create" will delete your database at start. "validate" or "update" might be better. Read the options here https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is struggling with this error, I fixed it by removing

```
<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
```

From hibernate properties.