# Integrating Spring MVC 4 and Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate 5 with Spring MVC 4 application, using "Spring in Action" book as an example, but something goes wrong.

Here is simplified version of the code:

WebConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("temporaryApp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

RootConfig

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"temporaryApp"},
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)})
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RootConfig {

    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driver);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setInitialSize(3);
        ds.setMaxActive(6);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sfb.setPackagesToScan("temporaryApp");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        sfb.setHibernateProperties(props);
        return sfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory(dataSource()).getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
}
```

IndexController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import temporaryApp.model.Message;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Message());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

SaveController

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import temporaryApp.dao.Dao;
import temporaryApp.model.Message;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/save")
public class SaveController {

    private Dao dao;

    @PostMapping
    public String save(@ModelAttribute ("message") Message message, Model model) {
        dao.saveMessage(message);
        model.addAttribute(new Message());
        return "index";
    }

    @Autowired
    public SaveController(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

Dao

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import temporaryApp.model.Message;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Repository
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
public class Dao {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void saveMessage(Message message) {
        Serializable id = currentSession().save(message);
    }

    @Autowired
    public Dao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Message

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:432)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    temporaryApp.dao.Dao.saveMessage(Dao.java:19)
    temporaryApp.dao.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e28af538.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    temporaryApp.dao.Dao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$efb69a17.saveMessage(<generated>)
    temporaryApp.controllers.SaveController.save(SaveController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:432)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    temporaryApp.dao.Dao.saveMessage(Dao.java:19)
    temporaryApp.dao.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e28af538.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    temporaryApp.dao.Dao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$efb69a17.saveMessage(<generated>)
    temporaryApp.controllers.SaveController.save(SaveController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't defined any strategy to your generated id for message.

By default, Hibernate will check on your database to find any sequence or strategy to generate values. Try this :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22473167/1722236

Comment: Dude you are too naive :-D actually i came accross the same error :-) and the copy/past was from my own code :D sorry buddy

Comment: I don't mean you stole the answer I mean that it was already asked and answered somewhere else, "buddy" ;).

Comment: OK, any way i just tried to help the one who answered, so basically if you believe that my answer could help him i don"t think you will act the way you did. have a nice day.

Comment: Just applying the advice here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled