# How to solve storing data with Spring Boot & Hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have below error when I try to store data in my database.

This is the entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="utilisateur")
public class Utilisateur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_utilisateur;

    @NotEmpty @Email
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty  @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private String role;

    ...
}
```

Of course I put getters and setters.

This is the controller:

```java
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public Utilisateur addUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) 
            throws RequestValidationException {

        Utilisateur utilisateur=new Utilisateur();
        
        utilisateur.setEmail(userRequest.getEmail());
        utilisateur.setPassword(userRequest.getPassword());
        utilisateur.setRole(userRequest.getRole());
            
        Utilisateur userAdded =  userRepository.save(utilisateur);
       
        return userAdded;
    }
}
```

```
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
```

the repository

```
     @Repository
      public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Utilisateur, 
      Integer> {

      }
```

When I try to store data I get the following Hibernate error: `error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work`

Comment: Set the following: `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22473167/13211030

Comment: Could you show your ```UserRepository```?

Comment: @Fullslack.dev  i tried but now the error is `SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using your classes, the following code block works just fine.

```
Utilisateur utilisateur=new Utilisateur();
        
utilisateur.setEmail("foo@bar.com");
utilisateur.setPassword("foobar");
            
Utilisateur userAdded =  userRepository.save(utilisateur);
```

Now that you mention ConstraintViolationException [null], chances are you are having troubles with the `userRequest` object. You should look for the list of constraint violations in your console logs. You can see which constraints are violated (`interpolatedMessage`) and which variables they pertain to (`propertyPath`).

```
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be empty', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.ecommerce.Utilisateur, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be empty', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.ecommerce.Utilisateur, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]
```